# Emails being sent "On Behalf Of" incorrectly and automatically

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

This issue has now happened twice in the last 2 weeks that I can find. The first happened when a user sent an email to a group of our clients.

System Setup

vSphere vHost running Exchange Server 2010 - Version: 14.01.0438.000

```
-----Original Appointment-----
From: Anay Bedi
Sent: Monday, July 29, 2013 1:18 PM
To: Anay Bedi; Recipient A; Recipient B; Recipient C; Recipient D; Recipient E; Recipient F; Recipient G; 
Subject: Developing Structured Peer Review: Driving Accountability and Remediating Disputes
When: Friday, August 16, 2013 10:30 AM-11:30 AM (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada).
Where: Virtual Conference via WebEx
```

---

When it showed up on the clients side, it looked like this:

```
-----Original Appointment-----
From: Recipient A On Behalf Of Anay Bedi
Sent: Monday, July 29, 2013 3:34 PM
To: Anay Bedi; Recipient A; Recipient B; Recipient C; Recipient D; Recipient E; Recipient F; Recipient G; 
Subject: FW: Developing Structured Peer Review: Driving Accountability and Remediating Disputes
When: Friday, August 16, 2013 10:30 AM-11:30 AM (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada).
Where: Virtual Conference via WebEx
```

---

Then when someone replied all it looked like this

```
-----Original Appointment-----
From: Recipient B On Behalf Of Anay Bedi
Sent: Monday, July 29, 2013 3:39 PM
To: Anay Bedi; Recipient A; Recipient B; Recipient C; Recipient D; Recipient E; Recipient F; Recipient G; 
Subject: FW: FW: Developing Structured Peer Review: Driving Accountability and Remediating Disputes
When: Friday, August 16, 2013 10:30 AM-11:30 AM (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada).
Where: Virtual Conference via WebEx
```

---

You can see that there are On Behalf Of located on the 2nd and 3rd message examples. This again happened on an internal meeting invite when a user hit Accept, she sent emails back to all of the people on the original invite that looked like the same invite was coming on her behalf and was acceptable.

Is this some kind of bug or virus?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when someone forwards a meeting to another user. For example, Anay invites Jillene to a meeting. Jillene decides that Leon needs to attend so she forwards it to Leon. The message is sent on behalf of Anay so that Leon knows it's Anay's meeting.

Comment: Yes but this user didn't forward. It came straight from us looking like that. I've already confirmed with the end users on both occasions. Neither made any action yet.

Comment: Are the people who received the messages delegates of Recipient A and Recipient B? By default, they will receive copies of meeting invitations.

Comment: No, they are at 2 different orgs on 2 separate servers. No one has delegates or control over another person.